# How to create a resposnive search filter with React

Tags: reactjs, object, filter, react-hooks, state

I have a DogCardsDisplayed React Component which maps through an Array of objects that displays the data in cards to the page. My SearchBar Component searches through the the array and filters the list in the console based on user search. How do I apply that to the actual cards so that the cards themselves are filtered on the page.

```
const dogData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Hollie",
    breed: "Doberman",
    age: 3,
    weight: 20,
    height: 150,
    img: "https://placedog.net/500/200?id=61",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Charles",
    breed: "Beagle",
    age: 4,
    weight: 20,
    height: 150,
    img: "https://placedog.net/500/200?id=100",
  }
```

```
import DogCardsDisplayed from "./DogCardsDisplayed";
import dogData from "./dogData";
import { Nav, Navbar, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

function SearchBar() {
  const onSub = (e) => {
    let substring = e.target.value;
    let filteredData = dogData.filter(
      (item) =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(substring.toLowerCase()) ||
        item.breed.toLowerCase().includes(substring.toLowerCase())
    );
    console.log(filteredData);
  };
  return (
    <Navbar className="d-block">
      <form>
            <input
              onChange={onSub}
              className="search-input"
              placeholder="Search"
              name="search"
            ></input>
            <Button
              variant="outline-light"
              className="search-button"
              type="submit"
            >
              Search
            </Button>
      </form>
    </Navbar>
  );
}

function DogCardsDisplayed() {
return dogData.map((item) => (
    <Card key={item.id} className="card">
      <div>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.img} />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{item.name}</Card.Title>
          <div className="d-flex">
            <div><b>Breed:</b> {item.breed}</div>
            <div><b>Age:</b> {item.age}</div>
            <div><b>Weight:</b> {item.weight}lb</div>
            <div><b>Height:</b> {item.height}in</div>
          </div>
        </Card.Body>
      </div>
    </Card>
  ));
}

function SearchPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <SearchBar />
      <div className="d-flex flex-wrap sp-body">
        <DogCardsDisplayed />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default SearchPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by storing the filter in the state (`useState`)[1] and then using `useMemo` [2] to return the filtered data based on changes to the state filter and the `dogData`.

```js
function SearchBar({ onSearch }) {
  const onSub = (e) => {
    onSearch(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  return (
    <Navbar className="d-block">
      <form>
            <input
              onChange={onSub}
              className="search-input"
              placeholder="Search"
              name="search"
            />
      </form>
    </Navbar>
  );
}


function DogCardsDisplayed({ dogData }) {
  return dogData.map((item) => (
    <Card key={item.id} className="card">
      <div>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.img} />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{item.name}</Card.Title>
          <div className="d-flex">
            <div><b>Breed:</b> {item.breed}</div>
            <div><b>Age:</b> {item.age}</div>
            <div><b>Weight:</b> {item.weight}lb</div>
            <div><b>Height:</b> {item.height}in</div>
          </div>
        </Card.Body>
      </div>
    </Card>
  ));
}

function SearchPage() {
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState("");

  const filteredData = React.useMemo(() => { 
     if (filter == "") return dogData;
     return dogData.filter(
       (item) =>
         item.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter) ||
         item.breed.toLowerCase().includes(filter)
       );
  }, [dogData, filter]);

  return (
    <>
      <SearchBar onSearch={(searchTerm) => setFilter(searchTerm)}/>
      <div className="d-flex flex-wrap sp-body">
        <DogCardsDisplayed dogData={filteredData} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

References:

[1] useState hook - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

[2] useMemo hook - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo